# Interval of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n\geq0} \binom{2n}{n} x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, power-series

We consider the power series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\geq0} {2n \choose n} x^n}$. By Ratio Test, the radius of convergence is easily shown to be $R=\frac{1}{4}$.

For $x=\frac{1}{4}$, Stirling equivalent and Ratio Test imply that the series is divergent. For $x=\frac{-1}{4}$, Stirling equivalent and Alternating Series Test can be used to show the convergence of the series. Thus the interval of convergence is $\left[\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$.

My question: is there a (preferably simple ^^) method to determine the interval of convergence without using equivalents? My students don't know about equivalents.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} x^{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "using equivalents." Do you mean not using limit comparison? That seems like a strong requirement.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : as in "asymptotic equivalent" of a function.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: thank you for your comments. Limit Comparison Test is eligible but, since my students have no idea about equivalence of sequences (in the sense "limit of the ratio of the 2 sequences is 1"), the comparison has to be obvious (thus, no Stirling equivalent). To make it clear, everything from "Calculus" by Stewart can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&\frac{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\dots\cdot 2 \cdot 1}{(2n)^2 \cdot (2n-2)^2 \cdot \dots \cdot 2} \\ 
&=&\frac{(2n-1) \cdot (2n-3) \cdot \dots \cdot 3 \cdot 1}{(2n) \cdot (2n-2) \cdot \dots \cdot 4 \cdot 2} \\
&=& \prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\\
&<& \prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\left(1-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)}\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)!}}\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}} \, .
\end{eqnarray}
So $a_n$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$; as $a_n$ is clearly monotone, the alternating series test proves convergence for $x=-1/4$.

You can make a similar comparison to show that $a_n>\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n}}$, which proves divergence for $x=1/4$.

Comment: Very nice, splitting the rational product into the collapsing one with square roots.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\left.\binom{2n}{n}\middle/\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\right.
&=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{n^2}\\
&=4-2/n
\end{align}
$$
Thus, using the ratio test we need to find $x$ so that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}(4-2/n)|x|\lt1
$$
and that is when $|x|\lt1/4$.

However, if we use the binomial theorem, we get that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n=(1-4x)^{-1/2}
$$
which also indicates a radius of convergence of $\frac14$.

---

**Endpoints**

As zyx points out, $\binom{2n}{n}\ge\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$ since it is the biggest term in row $2n$ of Pascal's Triangle, and the sum of the $2n+1$ terms in that row is $4^n$. Thus, the sum of the series for $x=1/4$ diverges.

Since the ratio of terms for $x=1/4$ is
$$
\left.\binom{2n}{n}4^{-n}\middle/\binom{2n-2}{n-2}4^{-n+1}\right.=1-\frac1{2n}
$$
and the harmonic series diverges, we get that the terms tend monotonically to $0$$^\ast$. Since the terms for $x=-1/4$ alternate, the series converges for $x=-1/4$.

$^\ast\ $If $x\in(0,1)$, $-\log(1-x)\ge x$, Thus, if $a_n\in[0,1]$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then $\prod\limits_{n=0}^\infty(1-a_n)=0$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, knowing that identity doesn't tell you what the radius of convergence is because the identity surely only holds if $x$ lies in the circle of convergence in the first place...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: true, but the fact that it has a singularity at $x=1/4$ indicates that the series diverges outside that radius, but that requires complex analysis.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, the identity tells us the series blows up at a point of magnitude $1/4$, and rewriting it as $S(x)^2 (1-4x) = 1$ allows use of function-theoretic arguments (being in a contractible set away from the singularities of the square root function) to take square roots with impunity inside that radius.

Comment: @rob: I think you need to say more. A naive application of this kind of argument would suggest that $1 - x^2 + x^4 \mp ... = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ has infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: all I said was that since there was a singulrity at $x=1/4$, the series must diverge outside that radius. At least in the reals, the converse is false.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't get the point here: "Since the ratio of terms is $\left.\binom{2n}{n}4^{-n}\middle/\binom{2n-2}{n-2}4^{-n+1}\right.=1-\frac1{2n}$ and the harmonic series diverges, we get that the terms tend monotonically to 0."

Could you give details please?

Comment: @Taladris: Sorry for the delay. I have added an explanation.